# Calling Gradle task for only one subproject

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

How do I configure subprojects for Gradle and run a Gradle task from the `build.gradle` only for the current directory I'm executing the task from?

For example, suppose I have two projects in a parent folder:

- `root-project`

  - `project-1`
  - `project-2`
- `build.gradle`
- `settings.gradle`

I have project 1 and 2 included in the `settings.gradle` file:

```
include(
    'project-1',
    'project-2'
)
```

I have a task configured in the `build.gradle` file that I would like to call. I've nested the tasks within a `subprojects{}` block:

```
subprojects {
    ...
    task check(type: JavaExec) {
        main = MAIN_CLASS
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
    ...
}
```

However, the `build.gradle` is run for all subprojects that way.

How can I define all possible subprojects but only call a Gradle task for the current project I'm executing from (i.e., avoid calling the task for all subprojects)? I would like to do this with the current task name only (e.g., `gradle check`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking the task in a single project with `gradle check` is not possible.

You have two options:

- Leverage the model Gradle proposes, where tasks can be prefixed by the project name in a multi project build which removes the need to navigate to subprojects.

  - Which means invoking `gradle :project-1:check` or `gradle :project-2:check` depending on which task you want to run.
- Define the tasks to have different name in each subprojects. [See task rules](https://docs.gradle.org/4.7/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_rules) on how to define tasks with dynamic names.

  - Which means invoking `gradle check1` or `gradle check2`